# How to repeat a cyclic animation of an object/armature from command line with Blender API

Tags: python, animation, scripting, armature, command-line

I need to render a cyclic animation of an object-armature from the command line. At the moment I am stack on how to repeat the keyframes, ie how to copy the keyframes of the first time points and paste them at the end of the animation the same object. I was able to do that with 2 different functions. One uses 'NLA_EDITOR':

```
def extend_cyclic_animation_nla(obj, n_repeatitions):
    
    for obj_i in bpy.data.objects:
        obj_i.select = False

    bpy.context.area.type = 'NLA_EDITOR'
    bpy.ops.nla.action_pushdown(channel_index=1)
    obj.animation_data.nla_tracks["NlaTrack"].strips["Armature|mixamo.com|Layer0"].repeat = n_repeatitions
    bpy.context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

The second function uses 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR':

```
def extend_cyclic_animation_dopesheet(obj, n_repeatitions, frame_end):

    for obj_i in bpy.data.objects:
        obj_i.select = False
    
    bpy.context.area.type = 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR'
    bpy.context.space_data.dopesheet.show_only_selected = True

    obj.select = True
    bpy.ops.action.copy()
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = frame_end
    for i in range(n_repeatitions):
        
        bpy.ops.action.paste()
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current += frame_end  

    bpy.context.space_data.dopesheet.show_only_selected = False
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = tmp
    bpy.context.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

My problem is that they only work when I run them from the blender window. When I run them from the command line I get an error. the reason is that when I run the code from the command line in the background `bpy.context.area` seems to be set to None and None does not have an attribute 'type'. The error is:

```
bpy.context.area.type = 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

So, My question is given an object with a cyclic animation data, how can I copy (or repeat) the keyframes of that object and paste them at the end of the same animation from the command line? I am using blender 2.79.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it'll help you

**>>In the Timeline panel, display the layer property containing the keyframes you want to copy.

> > Select one or more keyframes.

> > Choose Edit > Copy.

> > In the Timeline panel containing the destination layer, move the current-time indicator to the point in time where you want the keyframes to appear.**

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I am talking about how to code it (without opening the blender window).